# Is end-weight a linguistic term or is there an other word for it?

Tags: linguistics, style-manuals

"Cambridge Grammar in Use" ( p.902), in the glossary, points to the term "Endweight" but I find it nowhere else as a linguistics term.

Is it because it is Cambridge Univ. Pr.'s own coinage? 
If not, could anyone please point me to other sources?

Comment: It's more of a stylistic guideline than anything else, so it's not a linguistics term except in an extremely broad sense.  I hadn't heard of it before, but googling turned up numerous hits.

Comment: Yeah, I thought as much.  (I too googled it once).  But I did coin a term which I believe to be more accurate, and that's 'penultimacy'. I wrote an essay on it.  the premise basically says that what is most important in a sentence is what comes just before the end.  Interested?

Comment: [Nordquist, at Thoughtco](https://www.thoughtco.com/end-weight-grammar-1690594), uses the term (and has a good article discussing the concept). You may rate [Leech and Svartvik_A Communicative Grammar of English](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=5NIWAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA211&lpg=PA211&dq=Endweight+sentence&source=bl&ots=JKVsdviSh1&sig=o9nooIGzky6dMsWKVw5eaM4nPkQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiVm9zGxJHWAhWoJcAKHdPuBYUQ6AEISzAG#v=onepage&q=Endweight%20sentence&f=false) as more authoritative.

Comment: Thanks.  Will have a good look.   I also found the term "Foregrounding", which is close to what I get at in my essay.

Comment: Yes, I've read the extract. Only, the argument, for instance with "He owes me 5 dollars," states that the amount is the focus. But I argue that "owes me" is MORE important, and so therefore my 'penultimacy' theory prevails. More here, if you care to read:   https://clasgtr.wordpress.com/2014/08/06/penultimacy-an-essay/

Answer (score 2):

End-weight is definitely a linguistic term, not just a stylistic term.

> END-WEIGHT (after Quirk et al. 1972) refers to the tendency of heavier
>   constituents to be localized later in sentences, all else being equal,
>   as documented extensively for English and several other languages
>   (though some languages exhibit the opposite, beginning-weight
>   tendency; Sect. 5.1).

**Source:** Quirk, Randolph, Sidney Greenbaum, Geoffrey Leech, and Jan Svartvik. 1972. A grammar of contemporary English. London: Longman.

Comment: So did Quirk coin the term?

Comment: The source suggests that the term appears after Quirk in 1972. So, it is possible that Quirk did coin the term to refer to this concept.